# How do I use a dropdown to filter on a df column in a plotly chart?

Tags: python, plotly-python

I am trying to filter a plotly line chart of expenses based on a dropdown menu of expense categories. Since not all expense types happen every month, I would like the chart to display the appropriate months and expense amounts based on the selected category. I.e. selecting "groceries" should yield a line chart with value 5 at month 9 and value 2 at month 10, while selecting "gas" would yield a single point of value 1 at month 9.

I am fairly new to python and I'm not sure what exactly isn't working. Each button has the properly associated x values, y values, and category labels, but they aren't filtering any data in the plotly object.

I haven't asked a question here before, so if I'm missing something, please let me know and I can provide more information. I have a reprex below and I really appreciate some help. Thanks!

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
budget = pd.DataFrame({"month":[9,9,10,10],
                       "year":[2020,2021,2020,2021],
                       "expense":[5,1,4,2],
                       "category":['groceries', 'gas', 'utilities', 'groceries']})

budget_fig = go.Figure()
budget_fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=budget.month, y=budget.expense))

budget_update_menu = []
budget_buttons = []

for cat in budget['category'].unique():
  budget_buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                          label=cat,
                          args=[{
                              'x': budget[budget.category == cat].month.values,
                              'y': budget[budget.category == cat].expense.values
                          }])
  )

budget_menu = dict()
budget_update_menu.append(budget_menu)
budget_update_menu[0]['buttons']=budget_buttons
budget_update_menu[0]['direction']='down'
budget_update_menu[0]['showactive']=True

budget_fig.update_layout(updatemenus = budget_update_menu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- For the figure you are creating, it's far simpler to use **Plotly Express**
- effectively you create a trace for each *category* using the **color** parameter
- the legend will do what you want.  Make categories visible / invisible by clicking on items within it
- have also built a drop down menu as well, from information in the figure created by **Plotly Express**

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

budget = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "month": [9, 9, 10, 10],
        "expense": [5, 1, 4, 2],
        "category": ["groceries", "gas", "utilities", "groceries"],
    }
)

fig = px.line(budget, x="month", y="expense", color="category").update_traces(
    mode="lines+markers"
)

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": t.name,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": [{"visible": [t2.name == t.name for t2 in fig.data]}],
                }
                for t in fig.data
            ]
        }
    ]
)
```

[image]

Comment: Can I add a second parameter to filter on in this framework? I.e. if I added a year variable to the df.